# File admin config.zip is 169.57 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB

Tags: git, github

I was copying some files in my folder and by mistakenly I added 169.57MB zip file and
because of not knowing about the zip file I run git command `git add .` and `git commit -m "new feature added"` and finally `git push origin bugSolver-214`

and when the process was running I saw zip file and terminated the process in middle by doing `ctrl + c` and delete the zip file and again done above steps `git add .` `git commit -m "new feature added"` `git push origin bugSolver-214`

I saw this msg

```
remote: error: Trace: cf3cf1a67efcc5bc0461f8937f71d0f505487379cc1a3c870b480c7cf60126a7
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File admin config.zip is 169.57 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
```

As I already removed the permanently zip file I can't see how I can remove `admin config.zip` file

So I made some changes in my code and tried to commit again but it still showing me same issue

I searched internet created new branch but same error even tried `git reset .` but no help

even tried this to  `git rm --cached "admin config.zip"`

```
fatal: pathspec 'admin config.zip' did not match any files
```

is there any way I can remove that `admin config.zip` file and commit my code again

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2100907/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+large+file+history

Answer (score 0):

One option, for getting rid of large files in past commits, is to use [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) (python-based, to be [installed first](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/INSTALL.md))

And use some [content-based filtering](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#_content_based_filtering):

> If you want to filter out all files bigger than a certain size, you can use `--strip-blobs-bigger-than` with some size (`K`, `M`, and `G` suffixes are recognized), e.g.:
>
> ```
> git filter-repo --strip-blobs-bigger-than 100M
> ```

Then a `git push --force` will update your branch (which is fine if you are the only one working on it)

---

In your case though, if this was done recently (just in the last commit), you could:

```sh
git reset --soft @~1
echo "*.zip">> .gitignore
git add .
git commit -m "re-add everything except zip files"
git push --force
```

Comment: Hi @VonC I tried your command but it still showing me same issue

Comment: @Vikas Which command? The second one assumes your last commit is the one where the zip was added.

Comment: I don't know how many time I tried `git add .` command  now what should I do ? 

Comment: @Vikas First make sure in which commit your zip file was added. The last one?

Comment: I think maybe the last 5-6th one I am not sure

Comment: @Vikas OK, then I recommend the first option: `git filter-repo` will get rid of that file for you, wherever it is.

Comment: so how to use `git filter-repo` ? I just run this command ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244136/discussion-between-vonc-and-vikas).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem recently, and this command did the trick.

git lfs migrate import --include="*.params"

In my case, a particular file (.params) was the culprit.

You'll have to install lfs to have it work.